# Drupal Module for arranging Nodes of special type into a table||chart

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I'm trying to map Nodes of special Types on the basis of their field datas in a table or a chart.

The table should look like this:[Table Example](http://jsfiddle.net/c9Xqr/)

Explanation: Table Header and first row are the datas of two specified fields. The node titles (rest of table) are mapped on the free table rows/columns according to their field values. Since i got no solution for this i tried to look for an approach with graphs. But it doesn't turn out as an easier way.

Maybe i've overlooked something. I would be really glad if anybody have a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really glad that I found a good and comfortable solution for my problem.

There are two modules available: [Views Table Group](https://drupal.org/project/tablegroup), [Views Merge Rows](https://drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows)

At the beginning, I had some problems with the settings. After a few tryings I got along with these: [image: Settings for View][image: Settings for Views Table Group][image: Settings Views Merge Rows] check "Use values of this field as a filter" instead of "Use the first value of this field"

Note: I've just seen the merged rows logged out! So you had to change the visibility/accessibility settings or just log out to check the table.

My result: 
 [image: Result on logged out view]